# Using Tweepy API Search to search for any element in a list

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to use Tweepy's search API to return tweets that feature *any* of the terms in a list, not only tweets that contain *all* terms.

```
twts = api.search(q=["Hello World!", "I love Python!"])
```

This returns tweets that contain both "Hello World!" and "I love Python!", but I want tweets that contain either.

Answer (score 2):

One of the [standard Twitter search operators](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators) is OR, which you may utilize:

```
api.search(q='"Hello World!" OR "I love Python!"')
```

Note that double quotes would enforce the "exact phrases" search.

Comment: Is it possible to filter blocked users and quoted Tweets?